# Can YUI3 IO utility serialize data automatically based on the given content-type header value?

Tags: javascript, yui

Here is my code:

```
  data[this.getColumn().key] = oNewValue;
  request = Y.io("admin/api/inventory/" + encodeURIComponent(this.getRecord().getData()._id), {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: data,
    on: {
      success: function () {
        fnCallback(true, oNewValue);
      },
      failure: function () {
        fnCallback(false, oNewValue);
      }
    }
  });
```

Where the data object equals `{price: 1200}`.

Right now, `{price: 1200}` is serialized as `price=1200` (I do not even know how it happens). Obviously, this is not JSON.

Now I can manually stringify `data` to a json string, but I was wondering whether YUI has a facility to stringify data to json automatically. Ideally, I would like just give `data` and have the json content-type set as well as the data stringified by YUI for me.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Y.io has no inherent knowledge that you want JSON data to be sent, so it will transform any object into essentially the same thing you would get if you sent a form along (form encoded).

If you want to get into automatic serialization, I would recommend taking a look at Y.Model and Y.ModelSync.REST. It handles all the IO for you, and simplifies code a great deal.

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/model/

And specifically: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/model/#model-sync-layers